# Build a dataframe in a nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested for loop, and I want to build a dataframe with it. Here is an example of my code:

```
for id in range( 3):

    for i in range(2):
    
        x = i + id
    
        y = id-i
```

My ids are three, I want to put the value of x and y for each id in one row. The output of the above code is as follow:

[image]

Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a nested loop, you could use numpy broadcasting to build `x` columns and `y` columns separately:

```py
import numpy as np
inner_loop_lim = 2
id_lim = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(id_lim)})
df[[f'x_{i}' for i in range(inner_loop_lim)]] = df[['id']].to_numpy() + np.arange(inner_loop_lim)
df[[f'y_{i}' for i in range(inner_loop_lim)]] = df[['id']].to_numpy() - np.arange(inner_loop_lim)
```

Output:

```py
   id  x_0  x_1  y_0  y_1
0   0    0    1    0   -1
1   1    1    2    1    0
2   2    2    3    2    1
```

If you absolutely need a loop, you can try the following that build `x` and `y` lists iteratively:

```py
x_list = []
y_list = []
for id_ in range(3):
    inner_x = []
    inner_y = []
    for i in range(2):
        inner_x.append(i + id_)
        inner_y.append(id_ - i)
    x_list.append(inner_x)
    y_list.append(inner_y)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(3)})
df[[f'x_{i}' for i in range(2)]] = x_list
df[[f'y_{i}' for i in range(2)]] = y_list
```

Comment: Thanks @enke. However, here I only provide a very simple example. I have to use the loop. I want to build a df which the x_0, x_1 and its columns should be filled with RMSE and MAPE metrics which calculated in a loop. And in the loop, when I use df[f'RMSE_{kk+1}' ] = RMSE in for that row, the final df has only one id.

Comment: @Sadcow Edited the code. See if it's something you have in mind.